# Puerto 3306 en uso en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo un problema en el puerto 3306 a la hora de abrir MySQL.

La salida del error es:

```
Problem detected!
03:32:28  [mysql]   Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqld-nt" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\my.ini" MySQL"!
03:32:28  [mysql]   MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
03:32:28  [mysql]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
03:32:28  [mysql]   or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

¿Cómo puedo reconfigurar el puerto 3306 en el archivo my.ini?

Comment: Hay otra instancia del servicio mysql corriendo. Es la misma y no la detuviste?

Comment: Tuve el mismo problema varias veces y aunque cambié el puerto nunca me funcionaba, solo activé el `Net Command` para que siempre que levante el servidor me pida permisos de administrador; personalmente, eso me solucionó el problema  en una máquina que tenía.

Answer (score 0):

Como dice el stack, tienes dos opciones:

1. Bloquear el puerto que se está usando (3306) o detener el servicio que lo este usando.
2. Reconfigurar el archivo my.ini colocando un nuevo puerto.

   ## original

   port=3306

Volver a iniciar tu servicio y ver si funciona. Posiblemente estés usando XAMMP o algún programa similar y eso causa el error.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes cambiar el puerto en el fichero `my.ini`, debido a que los ficheros de configuración varían en la cantidad de lineas dependiendo de la configuración, la forma más fácil es buscar y reemplazar la palabra `3306` por el puerto nuevo que deseas asignar.

Los hallazgos de `3306` serán el valor para las claves `port=` dentro del fichero `my.ini`.

Una vez reemplaces todos los hallazgos por el nuevo puerto, guarda los cambios en el fichero y reinicia el servicio de mysql para que los cambios se vean afectados, del contrario seguirá utilizando el mismo puerto hasta que se reinicie el servicio.